# text field autopopulate from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, textfield, auto-populate

I want to get data from database to text field by using autopopulate when i type data in text field using javascript can any one help to me please

Comment: are you using particular server side technologies, and particular client side frameworks, or you open to everything ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to solve that is for instance to use autocomplete control from jquery.ui and create service using language/server of your choose to get data from your db.

Configuring jquery.ui autocomplete is as simple as

```
  var availableOptions  = ["apple", "pear", "pineapple"]

  $( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableOptions
  });
```

just having input control

```
  <div>
     <label for="auto">Fruits: </label>
     <input id="auto" />
  </div>
```

So if you dont have thousands of data items above is one of the easiest ways.

Alternatively, having implemented web service you can query it ajax-style, configuring autocomplete plugin right way

```
  $('#auto').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.getJSON( "/api/search", {
        term: request.term 
      }, response );
    },
    search: function() {
      var term = this.value
      if ( term.length < 2 ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  })
```